# cabal dependency is not recognized by ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a project in a sandbox and it has a dependency (mongoDB). when I build the project it build fine but when I want to load a .hs file into ghci it says "Failed to load interface for ‘Database.MongoDB’". what is going on here ?

info : I create sandbox using `cabal sandbox init` instead of `cabal sandbox init --sandbox =.`

Comment: someone on haskell channel gave the following comment : "use the sandbox's ghci wrapper or it won;t be able to see the sandbox"

Comment: he also said : "sandboxes hide stuff from ghc, that's the point. ghci is ghc; it won't see inside the sandbox unless specifically run within the sandbox. which means the wrappers I mentioned, or stack/cabal exec ghci)"

Answer (score 2):

for documentation purposes I write the answer here.
with help of geekosaur from Haskell IRC chanell all I needed to do was :

```
stack/cabal exec ghci
```